# How to create a custom grid filter

Tags: adminhtml, grid, model

I have added a custom grid column using the field URL in a custom database:

```
$this->addColumn('url', array(
    'header'   => Mage::helper('companymodule')->__('Has Website'),
    'align'    => 'left',
    'index'    => 'url',
    'renderer' => new Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Grid_Renderer_HasUrl(),
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('companymodule/hasurl')->getOptionArray(),
));
```

And created this custom rendered:

```
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Grid_Renderer_HasUrl extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = trim((string)$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
        if (empty($value)) {
            return 'No';
        } else {
            return 'Yes';
        }
    }
}
```

As well as a custom model for the filter dropdwon:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Hasurl extends Varien_Object
{
    static public function getOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            'Yes'   => Mage::helper('companymodule')->__('Yes'),
            'No'    => Mage::helper('companymodule')->__('No')
        );
    }
}
```

This works fine unless you try to filter. I think it's trying to match the value 'Yes' to the value of `$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex())` (the URL field in the database table.) But instead of matching the URL field value itself, I am basically trying to filter by `((bool)empty($url))` so that the user can filter by whether or not this database entry has a URL or not.

How can I create custom logic for a filter like this?

Comment: try to change the code like this `'renderer' => Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Grid_Renderer_HasUrl`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try adding a custom filter callback:

in your grid:

```
$this->addColumn('url', array(
    'header'   => Mage::helper('companymodule')->__('Has Website'),
    'align'    => 'left',
    'index'    => 'url',
    'renderer' => new Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Grid_Renderer_HasUrl(),
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('companymodule/hasurl')->getOptionArray(),
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterHasUrlConditionCallback')
));
```

and add a method like this:

```
protected function _filterHasUrlConditionCallback($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (empty($value)) {
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
             "main_table.url IS NULL");
    }
    else {
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
             "main_table.url IS NOT NULL");
    }

    return $this;
}
```

note it's not tested; you may have to check for empty rather than null on the database; also make sure you have the correct table alias (if URL is not on the main_table).

Comment: Thank you! For some reason if I have 'filter'=>true in the addColumn array I get a fatal error, but without it, this works great. Any idea why I can't have 'filter'=>true ?

Comment: From what I can gather, you only specify a boolean in the 'filter' property when you want to tell Magento not to filter that column (i.e., 'filter' => false). Otherwise, you would put the name of a block that is used as a filter. See the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid_Filter_Type for an example.

Answer (score 3):

try adding a custom filter callback: Here we add new Role Name column to admin user grid.

in your grid:

```
$this->addColumn('role_name', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Role Name'),
    'index' => 'role_name',
    'type' => 'options',
    'options' => $this->getRoleName(),
    //'filter' => false,
    'renderer' =>  'Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Grid_Renderer_Role',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_roleFilter'),
));
```

and add a 2 method like this:

```
protected function _roleFilter($collection, $column) {
    $filterroleid = $column->getFilter()->getValue();        
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }        
    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $filterroleid));
    return ;
}
```

Add This method for Role Filter with drop-down

```
public function getRoleName() {
    $rolename = array();
    $roles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getCollection();
    foreach ($roles as $role):
        $rolename[$role->getId()] = $role->getRoleName();
    endforeach;
    return $rolename;
}
```