# How do I add a custom dropdown filter in a grid

Tags: magento-1, grid, filter

This is my code:

```
   $this->addColumn(
       $key,
       array(
           header' => Mage::helper('core')->__($key),
           'index' => $key,
           'filter' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_filter_select',
           'sortable' => true,
       )
   );
```

I want to get all of the values from my column and put it in the dropdown options values and to filter them. Is there a way to do that ? At the moment I got an empty dropdown.

**[UPDATE]**

For instance if my values are 2,3,2,3,4,5,6,7 . I want to have in my dropdown the following values: 2,3,4,5,6,7

**[UPDATE 2]**

I managed to put the values in the dropdown. See My code:

```
$this->addColumn(
    $key,
    array(
       'header' => Mage::helper('core')->__($key),
       'index' => $key,
       'filter' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_filter_select',
       'sortable' => true,
       'renderer' => $render,
       'type'      => 'options',
       'options'   => $this->_getOrderType(),
      )
);
public function _getOrderType(){
        $types = new Varien_Object(array(
            "Frontend" => "Frontend",
            "AdminPanel" => "AdminPanel"
        ));
        return $types->getData();
}
```

But my filter doesn't work. If I filter after smth I got an empty grid. [image]

**[UPDATE 3]**

Update with the render function:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = $this->_getValue($row);
        if ($value == ""){
            return "Frontend";
        }else {
            return "AdminPanel";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the values come from, but you can use native's php `array_unique` function on the array of values, so the options would be unique.

Comment: can you check my post again, i made some updates. thx

Comment: I don't completely understand what you are trying to achieve here, sorry. But to answer your update - try adding the custom filter callback as described in here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21313/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-filter

Comment: Can you check my image that I attached. I just want to make a filter after the values from my dropdown. At the moment with my code , doesn;t work and I do not know why . Can you help me ? thx in advance :)

Comment: What is your `$render` variable? Can you update the post with the renderer?

Comment: Check now I did . If my row is empty show Frontend otherwise show Adminpanel

Comment: Is it the same result? The empty grid when you try to filter?

Comment: When I select an option from my select the grid is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use as below

```
$this->addColumn($key, array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('core')->__($key),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '80px',
        'index' => 'status',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options' => array(
            'Frontend' => 'Frontend',
            'Admin' => 'Admin'
        )
    ));
```